# Interpretation of method ASTs

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, julia

I'm trying to understand the ASTs of Julia methods. An example is the following function:

```
function inner(o, p)
  s = A1(o, p)
  s = s + A2(o, p)
end
```

Calling `show(code_lowered(inner, (Int64, Int64))[1])` will display something like

```
:($(Expr(:lambda, {:o,:p}, {{:#s908,:s},{{:o,:Any,0},{:p,:Any,0},{:#s908,:Any,18},{:s,:Any,2}},{}}, quote  # /home/pool/projekt/julia/grouping.jl, line 7:
    s = A1(o,p) # line 8:
    #s908 = +(s,A2(o,p))
    s = #s908
    return #s908
end)))
```

My question is how to interpret the part `{{:#s908,:s},{{:o,:Any,0},{:p,:Any,0},{:#s908,:Any,18},{:s,:Any,2}},{}}` it seems to be two local variables `{:#s908,:s}`. After this there are a number of symbols listed, both function arguments and local variables again, each have type information and an `Int`, what is this for? I'm guessing it is listing variables in the local scope and the `Int` is some sort of attribute? What are the possible values and meanings of these? Are they documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the true AST, you don't need to use `code_lowered`, just `quote`:

```
julia> ex = quote function inner(o, p)
         s = A1(o, p)
         s = s + A2(o, p)
       end end
quote  # none, line 1:
    function inner(o,p) # none, line 2:
        s = A1(o,p) # line 3:
        s = +(s,A2(o,p))
    end
end

julia> 

julia> dump(ex)
Expr 
  head: Symbol block
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Expr 
      head: Symbol line
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Int64 1
        2: Symbol none
      typ: Any
    2: Expr 
      head: Symbol function
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Expr 
          head: Symbol call
          args: Array(Any,(3,))
          typ: Any
        2: Expr 
          head: Symbol block
          args: Array(Any,(4,))
          typ: Any
      typ: Any
  typ: Any
```

You're looking at the annotated AST after removing syntactic sugar.